# HTML, CSS, JS, Canvas rectangle not deleting

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I would like the rectangle to move on the canvas and not copy every time.
It draws it but then the rectangle stays there.

I am a beginner with the canvas so if it is an epic fail then be prepared.

The codepen is at [LINK](https://codepen.io/Shadowunicorn1/pen/VbzmJx).

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var WIDTH = canvas.width;
var HEIGHT = canvas.height;
var boxWidth = 50;
var boxHeight = 50;
var bX = WIDTH / 2 - boxWidth / 2;
var bY = HEIGHT / 2 - boxHeight / 2;

function render() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.rect(bX, bY, boxWidth, boxHeight);
  ctx.fill();
}

function control() {
  bX++;
}

function main() {
  control();
  render();
}

main();
var run = setInterval(main, 10)
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: black;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas width="400px" height="400px" background-color="black" id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to _"repaint"_ the whole canvas at each iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repaint your canvas before drawing the rectangle each time - think about it. Its all done in layers.

The rectangle is "staying there" because you aren't replacing the rectangle your drew last time.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var WIDTH = canvas.width;
var HEIGHT = canvas.height;
var boxWidth = 50;
var boxHeight = 50;
var bX = WIDTH / 2 - boxWidth / 2;
var bY = HEIGHT / 2 - boxHeight / 2;

function render() {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height); //use clear rect instead

  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fillRect(bX, bY, boxWidth, boxHeight); //use fillRect instead of fill()

}

function control() {
  bX++;
}

(function main() {
  control();
  render();

  requestAnimationFrame(()=>main());
})()
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: black;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div>
    <canvas width="400px" height="400px" background-color="black" id="canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Also have a look at the requestAnimationFrame() method as opposed to setInterval - it syncs up with the window's javascript timer and is less likely to cause problems.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense but in codepen it isn't working.

Comment: @WLGBlog have a look at my edit - used the wrong method for clearing the first time!

Comment: It works! There is one problem. The white box is 50 by 50 but it looks like this:  [![Capture.png](https://s23.postimg.org/4egirmtob/Capture.png)](https://postimg.org/image/5gqpa6chj/)

Comment: @WLGBlog seems to look normal in the code snippet - thats really strange.

Comment: When I change the width or height of the canvas the box width and height ratio changes.